# rabbitmq-c SSL peer cert verification failed

Tags: c, ssl, rabbitmq-c

I'm trying to connect using SSL, SSL is enabled on the server but I'm not able to connect using the rabbitmq-c client.

I took the [amqps_connect_timeout.c](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c/blob/master/examples/amqps_connect_timeout.c) example and this is the error that I'm getting at amqp_socket_open_noblock.

`SSL peer cert verification failed`

When using OpenSSL the connection and verification succeed.

```
openssl verify -CAfile cacert.pem cert.pem
cert.pem: OK

openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:25586 -CAfile cacert.pem
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

If I disable certificate verification the connection succeed.

`amqp_ssl_socket_set_verify_peer(socket, 0);`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you pass the `-verify` flag to the `openssl s_client` command?

Answer (score 0):

I have found what was wrong, my CAfile was missing the intermediate certificate.
Probably openssl s_client is ignoring this by default.

After fixing the cacert file the connection was established from the rabbitmq-c library.